# Faster for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have a ~20 million row file, and I am trying to run a for-loop on it. I waited for the whole weekend but still, it wasn't even 1% done.

I am trying to make a calculation on a column of each row. If the value is <0.5 it will take and add that value to the new column if not, it will take the value and subtract it from 1, and add that value to the new column.

```
for (i in 1: length(halflife$year)){
  if(halflife$year[i] < 0.5){
    halflife$month[i] = halflife$year[i]
  } else{
    halflife$month[i] = 1 - halflife$year[i]
  }
}
```

It should add a new column with the name `month` to `halflife`, with all values less than 0.5

Comment: `halflife$month <- ifelse(halflife$year < 0.5, halflife$year, 1 - halflife$year)`

Comment: Since `ifelse` is not very fast, maybe faster would be to use a logical index: `i <- halflife$year < 0.5;halflife$month <- halflife$year;halflife$month[i] <- 1- halflife$year[i]`.

Comment: ifelse worked just fine! Thank you! Why was the loop taking so long?

Comment: @cookiemonster several 10 million function calls vs just a handful of function calls.

Comment: You might want to read [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Okay thank you all, I will read it

Answer (score 6):

This should be faster, using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)

halflife = data.table(halflife)
halflife[year < 0.5, month := year]
halflife[year >= 0.5, month := 1 - year]
```

Additionally, if you are reading your data from a csv file, use `fread()` from `data.table` instead of `read.csv()`. It's much faster

Comment: `setDT()` would be more efficient than converting with `data.table()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
halflife$month = halflife$year
ind = (halflife$year >= 0.5)
halflife$month[ind] = 1 - halflife$year[ind]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
library(data.table)       
halflife %>% data.table(.) %>% [,':='(ans = ifelse(year < 0.5, year, 1-year))]
```

If you want to learn data.table package, you can read the official cheat sheet from the DataCamp course first.(https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The relatively recent `fifelse` function of data.table can be amazingly fast on millions of rows. Try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(halflife)
halflife[, month := fifelse(year < 0.5, year, 1-year)]
```